# Wireless on Inspiron 1501 not working on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, wireless, inspiron

As titled, I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on an Inspiron 1501, and the wireless has refused to work thus far.

Below is what I have tried:

- Activating the Broadcom driver via System Settings > Additional Driver
- Using the below commands

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
  sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
  ```
- installing the cutter software

Sadly, none of them can get the wireless working. Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 1):

PLUG IN ETHERNET CABLE

Run these commands in terminal:

`sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source`

`sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer`

THEN UNPLUG ETHERNET AND REBOOT